# How to access a object from OBJECT class reference?

Tags: java

Could any one please help in following:

HelloWorld.java

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        HelloWorld he = new HelloWorld();
        Newfile ne = new Newfile();
        System.out.println(ne.a);
        he.puaa(new Newfile());
    }

    public String puaa(Object o) {
        System.out.println(">> " + o.a);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Newfile.java

```
public class Newfile {
    String a="paa";

    public static void main(String []args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I am passing `NewFile()` to `Object` class and trying to access variable of that object using Object's reference and i am getting

```
HelloWorld.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println(">> " +o.a);
^
symbol:   variable a 
location: variable o of type Object
```

**Update**: I want to pass any object to puaa(Object o) method and that object will have variable a always. So solution should be like that it should work for all not for NewFile only.

Comment: there is a way to do what you want look at my answer. You can try casting to each class one by one catching `ClassCastException` if it is thrown and trying to cast to the next `class` if it is thrown. You can do this until you find the right class. If you don't want to create a parent interface or `class` then I would suggest trying this...

Answer (score 1):

`Object` is a very generic class, and it doesn't have any field called a. You have some solutions to this:

- Make the parameter be a `NewFile` instead of any object. This is the better one in my opinion because, apparently, `puaa` is made to operate only on a `NewFile`object.

  ```
  public String puaa(NewFile o) {
  ```
- Cast `o` to `NewFile`. I don't recommend this, because if you pass something that's not a NewFile instance it will throw an exception, and so it's better the first solution than this.

  ```
  System.out.println(">> " + ((NewFile) o).a);
  ```

Comment: What if you don't send a NewFile object reference, but reference to other object which is stucturly same like OldFile() . I want reference which could hold any type and which convert into any type

Comment: @fatherazrael that cannot be achieved. Java has strong typing. Unless `OldFile` extends `Newfile`, this won't happen, but you have to understand that that will be a very odd design.

Comment: Then, make `OldFile` inherit `NewFile` or make both inherit a new class, which will then be the parameter type.

Comment: i am trying using another interface which implements by Newfile and Oldfile. But still getting an issue i.e that interface should have variable a declared in it

Comment: You must declare `a` in that interface you are creating. Also note the parameter type will have to be that interface now.

Comment: that is problem. that i do not want. i have 15 different objects like this an i could not make interface this very time. Any other solution you know? Either in Java 8?

Comment: Actually Puaa is not made to operate on Newfile only. But for Newfile type objects.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. `Object` can be anything: a `String`, an `Integer`, a `HashMap`, an `ExecutorService`... and from these 4 examples, none of them are closely related to your `NewFile` class.

The best alternative will be declaring a super (abstract maybe) class or an interface for your classes and pass an argument of this super type to the method.

Here's a small example:

```
public abstract class MyFile {
    protected String a;

    public MyFile(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }
}

public class NewFile extends MyFile {
    public MyFile(String a) {
        super(a);
    }
}

public class OldFile extends MyFile {
    /* add your implementation... */
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //you can replace here by using new OldFile
        MyFile myFile = new NewFile("foo");
        Main main = new Main();
        main.puaa(myFile);
    }

    public void puaa(MyFile myFile) {
        System.out.println(myFile.getA());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create interface

```
public interface HasA { 
  String getA();
}
```

Add this interface on all classes that you want to use with puaa

```
public void puaa(HasA o){
  System.out.println(">> " + o.getA());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to cast it to a `NewFile` object. It is looking at the base `Java` class `Object` for a method `a` which doesn't exist.

```
System.out.println(">> " + ((NewFile)o).a);
```

You can try casting to each class one by one catching `ClassCastException` until you get the class you want.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza then you handle the `ClassCastException` that is thrown.

Comment: It won't compile since Object do not have attribute "a"

Comment: @sunrise76 it compiles due to the downcasting.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza like I said before you handle the thrown `Exception`. It depends on what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Emd4600 never said it wasn't better. Just gave him a quick easy answer. And if you read his other comments this is actually what he wants.